# Login loop (xset cannot open display)

Tags: xubuntu, display, xfce, lightdm

For unknown reasons I have a login loop, I can login via terminal at the login screen, though I see a message about xset not being able to open the display. `ls -lah | grep -i Xauthority` shows my username and i've also tried `export DISPLAY=0` + `xset q` but neither help.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this? I'm using Xubuntu 20.04/AMD x64. Everythings been fine for months, i'm sure all of my drivers are fine.

Any help much appreciated.

Edit: `systemctl status lightdm.service` gives a number of errors attached in the image, does anyone have any idea what's gone wrong?

[image: lightdm]

Comment: Login loop happens when XWindows fail to start after successful login. There a many questions addressing the same problem. Here is one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop. However, this should not be caused by a reboot?

Comment: Yes I cant say what caused the problem, only that it happened after reboot. Ive checked Xauthority, reconfigured lightdm and i'm sure all my drivers are fine. I can access recovery mode but I cant see the 'minimal graphics' option do you know if its been removed or moved? Thanks for posting

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install gdm3
```

fixed the issue.